# Creating a Dynamic Scatterplot

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, filter

I want to create a scatterplot based on a filtered set of data.

I found this website: https://wellsr.com/vba/2018/excel/creating-vba-scatter-plots/

This returns data labels from the first several rows.

```
lastrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For countryRow = 2 To lastrow
    ochart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(countryRow - 1).DataLabel.Text = Cells(countryRow, 1).Value
Next countryRow
```

I want data labels based on the *filtered rows*. How do I loop through the filtered labels only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, This applies to all charts in the sheet.

```
Sub setLabelPoints()
    Dim myCht As ChartObject
    Dim n  As Long, k As Long, i As Long
    Dim adr As String
    Dim p As String
    Dim Cht As Chart

    
    For Each myCht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
        With myCht.Chart
            For k = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
                adr = .SeriesCollection(k).Formula
                adr = Split(adr, ",")(1)
                n = 0
                For i = 1 To Range(adr).Cells.Count
                    If Range(adr)(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
                    Else
                        n = n + 1
                        p = Range(adr)(i).Offset(, -1).Value
                       .SeriesCollection(k).Points(n).HasDataLabel = True
                       .SeriesCollection(k).Points(n).DataLabel.Text = p
                    End If
                Next i
            Next k
        End With
    Next myCht
 End Sub
```